# Artifacts on transparent Background

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jframe

I've got a JLabel in a JFrame with a semi-transparent background, but I'm getting some artifacts around the letters.

[image: Screenshot of the Artifacts]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World!");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128, 128));
        //label.setOpaque(false);
        //label.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        //((JPanel) frame.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
        //((JPanel) frame.getContentPane()).setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I already tried applying opacity to these components without luck. I'd like all Components to be fully opaque, so java7 per-pixel transparency for the JFrame seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can't just use Colors with transparency as a background. See [Background With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation and potential solution.

Comment: This post refers to background colors being reapplied and so becoming more and more intransparent, but doesn't deal with the artifacts around the letters.

Comment: @NCode The posting deals with the responsibility of a component with an opaque property to guarantee that the background of the component is fully painted. When you use a transparent color on an opaque component you can have painting problems. The posting gives an `example` of what might happen. It does not limit what the painting problems might be.

Answer (score 2):

I can't to reproduced your issue, maybe I'm out-off battery, but isn't there some issue with your GPU ???

[image] [image]

I tried suggestion by @camickr, nothing wrong happened

[image]

and

[image]

based on code from tutorial [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TranslucentWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TranslucentWindow() {
        super("Test translucent window");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(new JButton("test"));
        this.add(new JCheckBox("test"));
        this.add(new JRadioButton("test"));
        this.add(new JProgressBar(0, 100));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        panel.add(new JLabel("Very long textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "));
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Window w = new TranslucentWindow();
                w.setVisible(true);
                com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(w, 0.7f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two problems: 1. You are using the old AWTUtilities, wich became unusable with Java 7, so you should use Window.setOpacity(...), but 2. both functions set a global transparency, I want only the background to become transparent, the Components should be fully opque.